# How to define the colors of borders in shapfile?

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra

For this shape file

```
  library(terra)
  library(ggplot2)
  v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))
  ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2), color = "black")
```

For the moment, the color of the borders of each polygon is black. I need the color of the border of each polygon to be the same as the fill color of each polygon.

color = NA  is not what I need

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `color` aesthetic based on the same color as the fill like this:

```r
library(terra)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra"))
ggplot(v) +
  geom_spatvector(aes(fill = NAME_2, color = NAME_2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>